# A regular expression which will match all Or, It and And words in the string without . or : before these words

Tags: regex

I am looking for a regular expression which will match all Or, It and And words in the string without . or : before these words.

For example I want the following behavior:

- ". And", ":       Or", ".   It"  --> not match
- "And", "Or", " It" -->    match

It quite easy to get opposite result. This `(:|\.)+ *((\bIt\b)|(\bOr\b)|(\bAnd\b))` will match   ". And" and will ignore "And", however this is not what I need.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

negative look-behind is your friend: `(?<![.:] )(And|Or|It)`

Comment: This does not match ". Or" - cool, however it matches Or in ".   Or" (multiple spaces between dot and or). Is there a way to say - do not match if there are 0 to n white spaces between . and Or?

Comment: Something like this (?<![.:] {0,3})(And|Or|It) does not work unfortunately :(

Comment: Look-behinds with variable-length are impossible. `(?<![.:])\s+(And|Or|It)` won't work cause it will match string with one less whitespace, than it is actually.

Comment: Thank you for help! This workaround seems to solve the problem: (((?<![\.:])(?<![\.:] )(?<![\.:]  ))(\bAnd\b|\bOr\b|\bIt\b)) . It will not match if there are 0 to 2 spaces between . or : and word. Quite dirty, but works as needed